# Custom rails routes not using :id column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am attempting to create a custom rails route that allows me display information based upon the url. For example, I have products in a database with `category_id`s and `country` of origin fields. I would like to be able to type something like `/products/(category_id)/canada` or something to list items that match that category and country however my attempts have (obviously) been unsuccessful.

So far I've attempted

```
match 'products/:category_id/:country', to: "products#var_show"
```

and had no luck.

I've even just tried to make a route that shows the product via the serial code but rails seems to think I'm looking for an id even though I've specified the field in the route and in the controller.

```
match 'products/:serial', to: "products#show"
```

Can someone lead me in the right direction and show me what I'm doing incorrect? Thanks.

**edit:**

Rails seems to make the parameter :id no matter what I call it in the route and controller

```
Processing by ProductsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"481598745"}
```

Ideally that would be `Parameters : {"serial" => "481598745"}`  in the second case I asked about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
match 'products/:category_id/:country' => 'products#show',:as => :show
```

Comment: I do not want to search products by :id. I want it to return products matching a certain :category_id and :country or by :serial. Even after changing this and trying it, I am getting the same behavior I was getting with rails using number as :id.

Comment: Updated my question with a little bit more of whats happenening. Rails is treating that :{variable} as :id no matter what it seems.